# How do you implement no-autocomplete class in algolia wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, autocomplete, algolia

I cannot use the no-autocomplete class in my wordpress plugin for algolia,

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-autocomplete-post-suggestion">
  <a class="suggestion-link" href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}">
    <# if ( data.images.thumbnail ) { #>
      <img class="suggestion-post-thumbnail" src="{{ data.images.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ data.post_title }}">
      <# } #>
      <div class="suggestion-post-attributes">
        <span class="suggestion-post-title" >{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}</span>
        <!-- <# if ( data._snippetResult['content'] ) { #>
        <span class="suggestion-post-content">{{{ data._snippetResult['content'].value }}}</span>
        <# } #> -->
      </div>
      <div class="suggestion-taxonimies-attributes">
        <# if ( data.taxonomies.product_visibility == "outofstock") { #>
          <span class="suggestion-taxonomies-product-visibility ">Out of Stock</span>
          <div class="suggestion-taxonimies-attributes">
            <# if ( data.taxonomies.product_visibility == "exclude-from-search") { #>
              <span class="no-autocomplete"></span>
              <# } #>


            </a>
          </script>
```

Here is the specific code I am looking at to implement.

```
<div class="suggestion-taxonimies-attributes">
            <# if ( data.taxonomies.product_visibility == "exclude-from-search") { #>
              <span class="no-autocomplete"></span>
              <# } #>
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you are trying to achieve?
I you want to not display some results, maybe a better solution is to not index those.
In any case, a better place to discuss those matters would be the forum here: https://discourse.algolia.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try this code:

```
$('#tmpl-autocomplete-post-suggestion').append('<div class="suggestion-taxonimies-attributes"><# if ( data.taxonomies.product_visibility == "exclude-from-search") { #><span class="no-autocomplete"></span><# } #>');
```

Comment: I'm currently using a php file and it is a wordpress plugin.

Comment: I tried using this but it still isn't excluding the particular taxonomy attribute from search results : /